# Search within Laravel's eager loading

Tags: php, laravel-5, eager-loading

I have optional route written like this

```
Route::get('{id}/{inid?}/{task?}', 'WelcomeController@station')->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'inid' => '[0-9]+']);
```

and the controller like this

```
public function station($id, $inid = null, $task = null)
{
    $obj = Station::findOrFail($id);
    $template = 'station';
    $app = array(
        'docTitle' => $obj->st_name,
        'lat' => $obj->st_lat,
        'lng' => $obj->st_lng,
        'appName' => $obj->setting->set_name,
        'linkId' => $id
    );      
    if ($inid) {
        $obj = $obj->instruments()->where("in_id", $inid);
        $template = 'form.index';
        dd($obj);           
    }

    return view($template, compact('obj', 'app'));
}
```

now what I failed actually how do I fetch the `instrument` using the specified `$inid` within `$obj` of model `Station`

Here is how I set the model

```
class Station extends Model {

    public function instruments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Instrument', 'in_stid');
    }
}
```

and as for the instrument

```
class Instrument extends Model {

    protected $primaryKey = 'in_id';
    public function station()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Station', 'in_stid');
    }
}
```

Hope somebody can show me where can I look in official docs for solving this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

Replace

```
$obj = $obj->instruments()->where("in_id", $inid);
```

with

```
$obj = Station::where('id', $id)->with(['instruments' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('in_id', $inid);

}])->get();
```